# Squid proxy on cent os blocks everything

Tags: centos, squid, esxi

When I install squid forward proxy on a centos 7 vm and then tell a ubuntu vm to use the centos vm as a proxy squid blocks everything, this happens even if i create a new centos vm and install a fresh version of squid. If i change nothing in squid the problem still persists. I have created these vms in esxi 8

i have tried writing in the squid.conf file http_access allow all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your config? Are you using Squid on CentOS 7 with `SELinux` enabled? Do the command `getenforce` to find out. If its output says `Enforcing`, then SELinux is enabled and you should interact (start/stop/make changes) to Squid [the same way the RedHat documentation specifies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-managing_confined_services-squid_caching_proxy).

With Squid, you should add a new [acl](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) in the config that references your Ubuntu servers ip.
Example: `acl ubuntu src 216.128.143.117/32`

Then, you should add a new [http_access](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_access/) directive that allows your acl to access Squid.
Example: `http_access allow ubuntu`

I have a feeling you are using a local ip address, so you'll have ensure Squid is configured to allow traffic from local IPs. If you are adding an `http_access allow all` directive (not reccomended), then make sure it's above the `http_access deny all` directive, if it exists.

On Ubuntu, you can [enable an http/s proxy by doing](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-proxy-settings):
`export http_proxy="http://{host}:{port}/"` for an http proxy, and
`export https_proxy="https://{host}:{port}/"` for an https proxy.
This will forward all http and https requests to the server specified.

Add those directives to a users `.bashrc` file to make it permanent for *that* user, or add them to `/etc/environment` to make it permanent systemwide.

In case you're still struggling, I tested it out myself and got it working within minutes.
I deployed 2 servers on Vultr in Dallas, Texas:
One running `CentOS 7 SELinux`, and the other `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`.

On the CentOS server, I did the following:
`sudo yum update`
`sudo yum install squid`
`sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=3128/tcp --permanent`
`sudo firewall-cmd --reload`
`nano /etc/squid/squid.conf` and added:
`acl ubuntu src 216.128.143.117/32` and `http_access allow ubuntu`
Then, I did `systemctl start squid.service`

My `squid.conf` looked like this:

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
##########
acl ubuntu src 216.128.143.117/32
##########
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
#
# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
##########
http_access allow ubuntu
##########
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

On the Ubuntu server, I did:
`sudo apt-get update`
`export http_proxy="http://216.128.131.111:3128/"`
`export https_proxy="https://216.128.131.111:3128/"`
Then I did `curl ipinfo.io/ip` and the response was `216.128.131.111`, my CentOS server ip.